# Junction box cover required for a non-light ceiling device, and if yes, which one?

Tags: ceiling, code-compliance, junction-box

I am installing one of [these infrared heating panels](https://www.wexstar.com/product-page/frameless-ceiling-infrared-700-watts) hardwired on my ceiling.

My plan is to put a junction box into the ceiling (same size as a ceiling light), located underneath the panel. The wire to the panel will need to exit from the box somehow.

Can this box be left open behind the panel? In contrast to a light fixture, the panel is not fixed to then junction box but attached with separate screws.

If it should be closed, how?

Here is how this would look from the side:

[image]

Note that the (metal) junction box will not be flush with the ceiling because I need to fix it to the beam (there will be 1-2 drywell thickness in between). Also the cable that connects to the heating panel is not Romex. It will be a flexible cable, similar as the ones for lighting fixutures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two options:

##### Cord/plug

<s>I don't recommend this.</s> But the linked unit comes with a cord/plug. You can install a junction box flush to the ceiling and put a standard receptacle in it. The receptacle and matching faceplate form a cover for the box. **I did not originally recommend this method, but now that I know the hardwiring method is *not* by replacing the cord/plug with appropriate cable (NM cable or a wire whip) but rather by chopping the plug off and wiring the end of the cord into a box, I would recommend cord/plug installation.**

Plug in the heater and attach it to the ceiling. as long as the cord is not pinched, looped (too many loops will cause heating *in* the cord) or otherwise messed up you should be fine.

##### Hardwired

The factory installed cord connects to some sort of junction box on the back on the unit. I suspect (but couldn't easily find instructions) that hardwiring is done by:

- Open the integral junction box
- Disconnect the cord
- Connect a piece of NM cable (could be wire nuts or screw connections)
- Close the junction box
- Install a junction box on the ceiling
- Connect this NM cable to the wires in the junction box using standard methods
- The NM cable should be installed through an appropriate clamp in each junction box
- Install a blank cover on the ceiling box
- Install the device on the ceiling

Comment: Yes, I want to hardwire it and it is officially supported. I could not yet find a way to open then integrated junction box so I think I may need to cut the cord but I asked. Regardless, my question is about the OTHER junction box. If this box is in the ceiling, how would I attach a clamp? How would I route the wire out if there is a cover on it? Note, the jbox would look same as for a ceiling light. I hope my question is clear

Comment: It depends on the type of box. For example, with a metal box you can use [one of these covers](https://www.lowes.com/pd/RACO-1-Gang-Square-Metal-Electrical-Box-Cover/3128079) which has a 1/2" knockout and you put a clamp in the knockout. You are *not* allowed to cut the cord for a permanent installation because cords can't be used where NM is supposed to be used, and vice versa. You need to get instructions from the manufacturer about how to properly hardwire.

Comment: Oh I see. Ok I’ll get a metal box and this cover then. Good to know. But why not? I thought, the proper way is to cut the cord, strip it (=use as a pigtail) and then use wire nuts in the external junction box.

Comment: Is there likely to be a problem by cutting the cord and stripping it, etc.? No. But it is not to code. Code recognizes different types of cables for different situations. Cordage is designed to be flexible and also to be used in open air (which dissipates heat). Non-metallic cable (a.k.a., Romex) is not designed to be very flexible (bend it and it keeps its shape) but is designed to be run inside walls. One critical example is that cordage can, depending on the product, use thinner wire than standard for cables run inside walls. For a temporary fix cut cord/etc. would be fine. Not permanent.

Comment: I checked and I do not see a way to open the integrated junction box. I am sure I am supposed to cut the wire and use it as a pigtail. I do not think/believe I need to use Romex for this. Light fixtures don't have Romex all the way to to the fixture either. It's a flexible cable (similar as the one that's currently attached to the heating panel) which is then splied in the junction box. Regardless, I will wait for the vendor reply and post their response. I highly doubt they would offer a non code compliant hardwired option.

Comment: Also, things are still not 100% clear to me (even if I cut the existing wire). I added a schematic to my posting to be more clear. Are you saying I would still screw your suggested cover on it (possibly with longer mechanical screws) and use a clamp? Aren't these clamps only for Romex? (I am fairly positive one would not run Romex all the way to the heating panel)

Comment: I highly doubt they would offer a non-code compliant hardwired option, which is why I **don't** think they will tell you to chop the cord. It makes no sense. Yes, NM cable (Romex) is 100% fine in a situation like this. The issues with Romex are that it can't be used with something that moves around (this doesn't, you are mounting it to the ceiling) and that it needs to be protected from damage (a - not an issue on the ceiling anyway, b - the fixture blocks it anyway).

Comment: I got the following answer from vendor: “ To hardwire the units your electrician will cut the plug and will hardwire the heater by using the cable, but not the connection box. The connection box is not to be opened. Please note the hardwiring must be done by a certified electrician.”. As I expected they want to cut the cord. Do you have a NEC reference that shows that this is not code compliant?

Comment: Interesting. The usual rationale for it *not* being OK to do that is based on the type of cord. But if the vendor says so **and the item is UL or ETL listed** then I would get that in writing (if you already have it in an email that is enough - *save it*). If the item is not UL or ETL listed then together with this problem I would steer clear. Hardwiring a non-listed item, particularly in a usually inappropriate manner, is not generally a good idea, because if something were to go wrong you'd be in big trouble.

Comment: I am afraid it's not UL or ETL ... could not find anything in the manual or the website. I wrote Wexstar again. I am very disappointed by the product/company (it also doesn't look great, contrary as they advertise). Would not have expected this from a US/Canadian company. Regardless, as a backup, would it be "ok" to put an outlet in the junction box under the panel and just plug it in?

Comment: I got another answer from Wexstar and they said they are fully certified in North America which complies with UL. They provided this link: https://www.certipedia.com/certificates/72227479?locale=en and it states "UL 1278:2014 R2.22". Does this confirm it is UL listed and I can follow the manufacturer's instructions to cut wire?

Comment: Interesting. TUV is a European thing, roughly equivalent to UL and ETL. So that seems reasonable. That being said, the vendor's instructions mostly make sense (not 100%) but I caution you about one piece: *Please note the hardwiring must be done by a certified electrician*. That may be CYA for installation in general. But it may also be a hidden way of denying warranty claims. Admittedly, a device like this if it works on day one (which you can test by plugging it in) will probably last a long time. But they *could* deny a warranty claim if you send back a broken unit with a chopped cord and

Comment: are not able to show that an electrician did the work. Personally, I think I would go with: Install a receptacle in the ceiling box and plug this in with the original cord/plug.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Sorry, one last question before closing this: I want to turn on/off the device with a wall switch. Is it permissible to wire the outlet to a wall switch? I know this is allowed for lights (and often done for normal outlets) but I want to double check.

Comment: Yes, a switched receptacle is perfectly fine. The usual concern is that the receptacle might get used for other things that shouldn't be switched, but not an issue at all with a ceiling receptacle.

Answer (score 2):

It looks from your diagram that the panel will be spaced away from the ceiling surface.
There's no reason in the world to attach the junction box to the joists, or to have it buried inside the ceiling cavity. The only reason you need a junction box is to provide protection for the wire connections, which can be done with a surface-mounted metal pancake box, 1/2" or so deep. It can be mounted by using screw anchors in the ceiling drywall. The feed cable can emerge from a small hole in the ceiling and connect to the knockout hole which the pancake box will have in its back. It does not need a cover if the panel surface under it is non-combustible, which would astonish me if it was not. Light fixtures are installed all the time with no covers (other than the fixture itself) over the box.

FYI, it is not code-compliant to cut the plug off a flexible cord and use it to hard-wire a device.

Comment: Ok, I can use a surface mounted pancake box. However, I was thinking a larger and more rigid metal box gives me more flexibility and it makes me feel better if it's solidly attached to the beam rather than drywall. Further: There will actually be multiple of these heating panels and a larger and robust metal box would give me the option to splice them flexibly at multiple locations or install a relay for remote control. Is there a big reason not to "bury" the box (and attach to beam)? "Ceiling" on the picture is just normal drywall thickness.

Comment: "The feed cable can emerge from a small hole in the ceiling". Do I understand correctly that you'd drill a hole next to the junction box to feed the cable to the panel out?

Comment: I got the following answer from vendor: “ To hardwire the units your electrician will cut the plug and will hardwire the heater by using the cable, but not the connection box. The connection box is not to be opened. Please note the hardwiring must be done by a certified electrician.”. As I expected they want to cut the cord. Do you have a reference why cutting the cord would not be code compliant?